# Google Analytics behaving differently in development and production/staging

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I have one of my projects setup with analytics.js and Enhanced Ecommerce.

My staging site is subdomain.site.com, and for the site I have the cookie domain (analytics_domain) set to 'none' in development, and 'auto' in staging.

`ga('create', analytics_id, analytics_domain);
  ga('require', 'ec');`

The Enhanced Ecommerce is enabled and setup to track events and transactions.
I have the goals setup, using GA's template for creating an account/purchase, and tracking a specific event.

**Behavior problem:**

**Development**

Create an url for a campaign like this:

`localhost:3000/login?utm_source=test_campaign&utm_campaign=tcp&utm_medium=test_url`

Create an account and go through purchase.
I have in GA view, 1 create account event, 1 transaction_completed event and on eCommerce 1 purchase.

This is the expected behavior, I can see the events and have the transactions connected to that campaign.

**Staging:**

`https://subdomain.website.com/login?utm_source=test_campaign&utm_campaign=tcp&utm_medium=test_url`

Create an account and go through purchase.
I have in GA view, 1 create account event, 0 transaction_completed event and on eCommerce 0 purchases.

I can see the transactions on staging, I can see all the events, it's just they are not tied to the campaign.

I have created a Site Test, view and I use that code for development and staging. Since they share the same setup for the Google Analytics part I assume I'm not understanding something.

Things I did so far:
- Every test was done in Chrome incognito with no plugin enabled
- Tested the same transaction setup on staging multiple times, results are consistent
- Checked the cookie domain, is .domain.com on the cookie
- Checked throughout the transaction if the clientId for the user is the same (with analytics debugger), it is the same

I ran out of ideas and I really need to get this working so I can track paid campaigns.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was that with our third-party payment providers (like PayPal), the session was reset when the user returned to our success page.

**Solution:** add `?utm_nooverride=1` to your return url from each provider, and that should fix it.